# git submodule sync command - what is it for?

Tags: git, git-submodules

I don't understand from the [documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-submodule) what does `git submodule sync` do. Please explain.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

Git stores information about submodules in two places. The first is in a file called `.gitmodules`, which is checked in to the git repository. Changes to this file are what get propagated to other repositories.

The other location is in `.git/config`, and it's where git actually looks when performing most commands.

So imagine you've worked on a project for a while, and there's a submodule called `foo`. Files for this submodule are checked out from some url, it doesn't really matter where. At some point, however, this url changes. Perhaps it changes so that the submodule is checked out from a different server, or a different path or whatever. When you update your repository your copy of the `.gitmodules` file will be updated, but not your `.git/config` file; you would still be checking out from the old url. When you want to start checking out from the new url, you would run `git submodule sync` to copy the new configuration from `.gitmodules` to `.git/config`. Git doesn't do this automatically because you might have made your own changes to your configuration, and it wouldn't want to overwrite them.

Comment: I wonder if I manually need to change the link in `.gitmodules` what is the reason not to change the same thing manually in `.git/config` too? Or there would be a command that changes in two places?

Comment: There's no command that I know of which changes both at once, other than `git submodule add` which can be used to add new submodules but not change an existing one.

Comment: I mean it is strange to me that in one place you need to change manually and in other it is being changed by command, what you think?

Comment: I'm not sure anyone thinks the submodule commands are beautiful.

Comment: nice answer though :)

Comment: The submodule repository URLs appear in not two, but three places. They are also listed in .git/modules/..../submodule/config. I can't find where the latter is ever updated. "git submodule sync" does not do it. As a result, I get a lot of "SHA is not a tree" problems with submodules.

Comment: I actually have seen the `git submodule sync` command update the .git/modules/.../config file to point the origin URL as indicated by the .gitmodules file.

Comment: There is no ".git/config"  file on submodules. Only on the parent. And there is no info about my 5th level submodule there.

Comment: This answer should be obsolete, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77328136/git-submodule-sync-why-doesnt-it-do-anything for refutation