# Using Gitmodules with GitLab CI does not Work

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, cicd

I have a repository called "pipelines" where I have a .gitlab-ci.yml file that runs a script to perform a specific task.

I use repo mirroring to pull from the "pipelines" repo.

The job in the pipeline clones a repo called "source-repo" and runs a command inside that repo directory.

**.gitlab-ci.yml**

```
variables:
  GIT_SUBMODULE_STRATEGY: recursive

.maven:
    image:
      image: maven:3.6.3-jdk-11
      entrypoint: [""]
      
deploy:
  extends: .maven
  stage: deploy
  script: |
    mkdir -p /root/.ssh
    echo "${KNOWN_HOSTS}" > /root/.ssh/known_hosts
    chmod 600 /root/.ssh/known_hosts
    echo "${AUTH_KEY}" >  /root/.ssh/id_rsa
    chmod 600  /root/.ssh/id_rsa
    
    git clone -b master ssh://git@git.company.com:7999/projects/source-repo.git

    cd source-repo && mvn package
```

I wanted to add rules to the job that allows me to control when the pipeline job is created.
For example the "deploy" job should only be created when there are changes pushed to the "source-repo".

To achieve this I tried the following:

```
deploy:
  extends: .maven
  stage: deploy
  script: |
    cd source-repo && mvn package
  rules:
     - changes:
       - source-repo/
```

It didn't work because source-repo is a separate repository. Therefore, I tried `.gitmodules` to add the "source-repo" as a sub directory to the "pipeline" repo.

```
[submodule "source-repo"]
  path = source-repo
  url = https://git.company.com/scm/projects/cat-source.git
```

But, I still couldn't make it work. Is there something that I am missing?

Comment: Did you  just add the `.gitmodules` file? If so you would need to run `git submodule sync` (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33739376/git-submodule-sync-command-what-is-it-for). Or better yet, `git submodule add <repo> <dir_path>`.

Comment: On a side note, to move a submodule if need ever arises, use `git mv <path_old> <path_new>` (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4604486/how-do-i-move-an-existing-git-submodule-within-a-git-repository).

Answer (score 3):

The [`changes` keyword](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#ruleschanges) is used to identify changes in files within the same repository where the CI/CD pipeline is configured, and it cannot track changes in a separate repository, not even if it is added as a submodule.

[Submodules in Git](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules) are pointers to a specific commit... in *another* repository. The `.gitmodules` file holds the information about the submodules, such as the path and URL. However, even if you include "`source-repo`" as a submodule in your "pipelines" repository, GitLab CI/CD still recognizes changes in terms of the "pipelines" repository files, and not dynamically based on the files of the "`source-repo`" submodule.

---

To achieve what you are looking to do (I.e. triggering the "deploy" job based on changes in the "`source-repo`"), you will have to set up a CI/CD pipeline in the "`source-repo`" repository itself, instead of trying to control it from your "`pipelines`" repository. That way, you can utilize the `changes` keyword to monitor changes effectively in the "`source-repo`" repository and trigger the job accordingly.

---

However, if setting up a CI/CD pipeline in the "source-repo" is not an option, and you must control everything from the "`pipelines`" repository, you might need to create a script that checks for changes in the "`source-repo`" before deciding whether to run the "`deploy`" job or not.

The script might look something like this (to give a general idea):

```yaml
deploy:
  extends: .maven
  stage: deploy
  script: |
    # Your existing setup scripts here

    # Clone the source-repo to check for recent changes
    git clone -b master ssh://git@git.company.com:7999/projects/source-repo.git

    # Check for changes in the source-repo (this is a placeholder, you would add a script to check for real changes)
    CHANGE_DETECTED=$(./check_for_changes.sh) 

    if [ "$CHANGE_DETECTED" == "yes" ]; then
        cd source-repo && mvn package
    else
        echo "No changes detected in source-repo; skipping deploy job"
    fi
```

The `check_for_changes.sh` would be a script that you create to check for changes in the "`source-repo`" based on your specific criteria. It should print "`yes`" if changes are detected and the `deploy` job should run, or anything else if not.

Something like:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

# Define the remote repository
REMOTE_REPO="ssh://git@git.company.com:7999/projects/source-repo.git"

# Define a file to store the last seen commit hash
LAST_SEEN_COMMIT_FILE="last_seen_commit.txt"

# Fetch the latest commit hash from the remote repository
LATEST_COMMIT=$(git ls-remote $REMOTE_REPO HEAD | awk '{ print $1}')

# Check if the LAST_SEEN_COMMIT_FILE exists and has a value
if [ -f $LAST_SEEN_COMMIT_FILE ]; then
    LAST_SEEN_COMMIT=$(cat $LAST_SEEN_COMMIT_FILE)
else
    LAST_SEEN_COMMIT=""
fi

# Compare the latest commit hash with the last seen commit hash
if [ "$LATEST_COMMIT" != "$LAST_SEEN_COMMIT" ]; then
    # If they are different, update the last seen commit hash file and return "yes"
    echo $LATEST_COMMIT > $LAST_SEEN_COMMIT_FILE
    echo "yes"
else
    # If they are the same, return "no"
    echo "no"
fi
```

---

> This is a nice approach.
>
> However, if I use as a script like `check_for_changes.sh`, then I have to manually pass the last commit that I want to compare with the latest commit to the `LAST_SEEN_COMMIT_FILE`.
>
> I wonder if it is possible to determine the `LAST_SEEN_COMMIT` with a script?
> Let's say for example, the `deploy` job only gets created when a branch merges to `master` branch of `source-repo` and there are changes to files in `source-repo`.

You can modify the script to automatically determine the `LAST_SEEN_COMMIT` based on certain criteria.
To identify the last commit that happened before the most recent merge to the `master` branch, you can use Git commands to find the most recent merge commit and then find its parent commit (which will be the commit just before the merge).

The new and amended `check_for_changes.sh` script to find the last commit on the `master` branch before the most recent merge would be:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

# Define the remote repository
REMOTE_REPO="ssh://git@git.company.com:7999/projects/source-repo.git"

# Clone the remote repository to a temporary directory
TEMP_DIR=$(mktemp -d)
git clone $REMOTE_REPO $TEMP_DIR

# Find the hash of the most recent merge commit on the master branch
cd $TEMP_DIR
git checkout master
LAST_MERGE_COMMIT=$(git log --merges -n 1 --pretty=format:"%H")

# Find the hash of the commit before the most recent merge commit (parent commit)
LAST_SEEN_COMMIT=$(git log --pretty=format:"%H" -n 1 $LAST_MERGE_COMMIT^)

# Clean up by removing the temporary directory
cd ..
rm -rf $TEMP_DIR

# Print the hash of the last seen commit (before the most recent merge)
echo $LAST_SEEN_COMMIT
```

I clone the `source-repo` to a temporary directory, and use `git log` with flags to find the most recent merge commit on the `master` branch.
I use `git log` again with the merge commit's parent (`$LAST_MERGE_COMMIT^`) to find the commit just before the merge.

In your `.gitlab-ci.yml`, you would call this script to get the `LAST_SEEN_COMMIT`, and then proceed with the rest of your logic to check for changes since this commit and decide whether to run the deploy job.
Note that this script finds the last commit before the most recent merge to `master`, regardless of whether specific files were changed; you might want to add further logic to check for changes to specific files if needed.

Comment: Thank you for your response. This is a nice approach. However, if I use as a script like ```check_for_changes.sh``` then I have to manually pass the last commit that I want to compare with the latest commit to the ```LAST_SEEN_COMMIT_FILE```. I wonder if it is possible to determine the ```LAST_SEEN_COMMIT``` with a script? Let's say for example, the ```deploy``` job only gets created when a branch merges to ```master``` branch of  ```source-repo``` and there are changes to files in ```source-repo```.