# `git submodule sync`: why doesn't it do anything?

Tags: git, git-submodules, git-sync

Considering this commit:

https://github.com/tribbloid/spookystuff/commit/08650c3565a823fb1a696afd7f1461681293a1fe

If I run the following command:

```
peng@pop-os:~/git/spookystuff$ cat .gitmodules 
[submodule "parent/showcase"]
    path = parent/showcase
    url = https://github.com/tribbloid/spookystuff-showcasepeng@pop-os:~/git/spookystuff$ git submodule sync
peng@pop-os:~/git/spookystuff$ git submodule update --init --remote --recursive
peng@pop-os:~/git/spookystuff$ git submodule status
peng@pop-os:~/git/spookystuff$ git submodule foreach git pull --rebase
peng@pop-os:~/git/spookystuff$ git submodule status
```

It can be seen that the number of submodule is still 0, contrary to the .gitmodule file

How did this happen? And what can be done to fix it?

Comment: Did you manually change the `.gitmodules` file, or use `git submodule add` to properly add a submodule?

Comment: good question: it was cherrypicked from another branch, but apparently git cherrypick malfunctioned and only apply changes in `.gitmodule`. I'm still looking for the right command to cherrypick `.git/config`

Comment: I think the easiest solution is to just once run `git submodule add https://github.com/tribbloid/spookystuff-showcase parent/showcase`. That works even if your .gitmodules exists already, but sets the according .git/config correctly.

Comment: @TorgeRosendahl thanks a lot, it is probably impractical for a lot of submodules tho (e.g. PX4-autopilot)

Answer (score 1):

> Considering this commit:
>
> https://github.com/tribbloid/spookystuff/commit/08650c3565a823fb1a696afd7f1461681293a1fe

In this commit, `.gitmodules` is changed to indicate that the submodule `spookystuff-showcase` should be cloned at path `parent/showcase` instead of `spookystuff-showcase`. But, the actual submodule object is removed: https://github.com/tribbloid/spookystuff/commit/08650c3565a823fb1a696afd7f1461681293a1fe#diff-8f1d364786f7b7fb36c0cd2e5b73810d4d1b435acfc890dad6da02ac7bf95101.

This is why all `git submodule` subcommands do nothing: there is no submodule object at that commit in your repository.

If the intention was to move the submodule, then ideally `git mv spookystuff-showcase parent/showcase` would have been used.

To fix it, you should restore the changes to `spookystuff-showcase` and then properly move it:

```bash
git clone https://github.com/tribbloid/spookystuff
git fetch origin 08650c3565a823fb1a696afd7f1461681293a1fe
git checkout 08650c3565a823fb1a696afd7f1461681293a1fe
git checkout HEAD~1 spookystuff-showcase
git mv spookystuff-showcase parent/showcase
git commit -m "re-add spookystuff-showcase at path parent/showcase" # or git commit --amend --no-edit
git submodule update --init # works
```

Comment: thanks a lot, so there is no command to resolve this conflict?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "conflict". There is no Git merge conflict happening in the above sequence...

Comment: sorry I mean "inconsistency" between the .gitmodule file and the hidden commit reference under `.git` directory (which, if considered part of the project dependency, shouldn't be hidden)

Comment: Well, the commands I mention can be used to resolve the inconsistency. I'm not sure what else you would like to do ? maybe I'm missing something.

Comment: I'm afraid that's not a generalisable solution, first, it will be wildly verbose for projects with many submodules (e.g. PX4-autopilot), second, the problem arise from a cherrypicking, so the working tree will be lost if re-clone it from scratch